# Transaction Response Time Vs JDBC Response Time

Tags: performance, web, websphere

I have a spring application which we have deployed in a WebSphere server ( version 7.0 ).

We are moving to a new cloud based infrastructure , here we are having server performance issues.

On analysis with the "WebSphere Application Server Performance Tuning Toolkit" we see most of the response time analysis as follows ->

```
Servlet Response Time -> 824 ms
Transaction Time -> 782 ms
Jdbc -> 26 ms
```

Trying to understand what is the difference between transaction time and jdbc time. Can someone please help.

Comment: If you haven't yet, try the WebSphere forum: http://ibm.biz/websphere-forum

Comment: I suspect transaction time is the duration of the entire local transaction of the servlet, and JDBC time is only the time spent in JDBC methods (i.e., most of your time is spent outside JDBC calls).  I do not know the difference between servlet response time and transaction time (perhaps the latter does not include transaction commit?).

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. I will try the ibm websphere forum once ..

Answer (score 2):

Transaction Time is the time that a trasaction between HTTP Server and Application Server occurs and JDBC Time is the time between de Application Server and the Database.

For more informations see:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/tprf_requestmetrics.html